# How to install UFW via ansible (.yml)

Tags: ansible, apt, ufw

I found an [Ansible playbook](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-debian-with-ansible/) to install a LAMP server. Thing is Debian 11 does not include UFW in the default installation and the playbook tries to configure it and fails. I can remove these lines from the PB, but it would be great to be able to install UFW. Not sure how?

Here's the yml file:

```
---
- name: Install prerequisites
  apt: name={{ item }} update_cache=yes state=latest force_apt_get=yes
  loop: [ 'aptitude' ]

  #Apache Configuration
- name: Install Apache and PHP Packages
  apt: name={{ item }} update_cache=yes state=latest
  loop: [ 'apache2', 'php', 'php-mysql', 'libapache2-mod-php' ]

- name: Create document root
  file:
    path: "/var/www/{{ http_host }}"
    state: directory
    owner: "{{ app_user }}"
    mode: '0755'

- name: Set up Apache virtualhost
  template:
    src: "files/apache.conf.j2"
    dest: "/etc/apache2/sites-available/{{ http_conf }}"
    
- name: Enable new site
  shell: /usr/sbin/a2ensite {{ http_conf }}
  
- name: Disable default Apache site
  shell: /usr/sbin/a2dissite 000-default.conf
  when: disable_default
  notify: Reload Apache

# UFW Configuration
- name: "UFW - Allow HTTP on port {{ http_port }}"
  ufw:
    rule: allow
    port: "{{ http_port }}"
    proto: tcp

  # PHP Info Page
- name: Sets Up PHP Info Page
  template:
    src: "files/info.php.j2"
    dest: "/var/www/{{ http_host }}/info.php"

- name: Reload Apache
  service:
    name: apache2
    state: reloaded

- name: Restart Apache
  service:
    name: apache2
    state: restarted
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add additional tasks to install and enable UFW as given below.

```yaml
  #UFW Configuration
- name: Install UFW firewall
  apt: name=ufw update_cache=yes state=latest  
  
- name: Enable UFW
  community.general.ufw:
    state: enabled
```

Refer [ufw_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ufw_module.html) documentation for more configuration params.

Comment: Thanks - i get an error on the second part - name: Enable UFW

Comment: whats the error ?

Comment: The offending line appears to be:

  apt: name=ufw update_cache=yes state=latest
           ^ here

Comment: ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'community.general.ufw'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.

Comment: may be the collection is not installed. See the note at the top of this page: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/ufw_module.html. You can install it using this command: "ansible-galaxy collection install community.general"